# What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, stack-overflow-history

What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?

I am just curious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go, but you cannot see it with < 10k reputation.

Comment: That makes [When setting a form's opacity should I use a decimal or double?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4) the first *still visible* question.

Comment: meta dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/what-was-the-first-question-on-so

Comment: Tut. I was expecting it'd be a question by Jon Skeet, posted before StackOverflow was created, and of course answered by himself

Comment: @LuisMendo True. You are referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/-1 . That question existed before SO was created, but it is only visible to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Was the site sponsored financially when developing it in the beginning to get the first questions and answers out?

Comment: @Tut Jon Skeet existed before the universe was created.

Comment: @javadba: Then Jon Skeet is the new chuck norris

Comment: @v.oddou see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: "This is the closed beta - NO DATA FOR YOU!" -- huh, I guess the Soup Nazis were there from Day 1.

Comment: I wonder what the last question on Stack Overflow will be.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Since all posts are numbered sequentially, you just go to [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1); that post was a test question and has been deleted. It had 2 answers (post ids #2 and #3) so the first one still visible is:

[Convert Decimal to Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/convert-decimal-to-double)

which is post #4 on the site.

A screenshot of the now-deleted first post:

[image]

See [What was "the Joel Data"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266211/what-was-the-joel-data) as to what that post was about.

The post was deleted shortly after being created; Jarred Dixon asked it, Jeff Atwood didn't 'approve' and removed it again. Question #4 was created by a test account, posts [#6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6), [#8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8), [#9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9), [#11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11), [#13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13), [#16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16) and [#17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17) are all 'seed' content created by Jeff Atwood, Geoff Dalgas and Kevin Dente, with another [question #14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14) being a seed question using a test account; these were posted before the first outside beta testers were given access.

So you could also say that [What is the fastest way to get the value of π?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-value-of-%CF%80) is the very first, it is the first question that is *not* test or seed content.

Comment: Wow that question (#4) is a mess.

Comment: FYI #4 also seem to be a test question.  The original OP description: http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren

Comment: @AaronLS: before August 1st there were only the developers and maybe 2 outside users registered, next to test accounts. With the public beta starting on August 1st, anything posted before that are either tests or seed content. The first 'outside' question is number 19, I'd say.

Comment: Is there no snapshot of when it wasn't deleted?

Comment: @0x499602D2: probably not, as it was deleted within hours of posting.

Comment: "Last Edited 12 hours ago" (post #4)

Comment: @justcool393: a rollback on a useless edit made in January. The post *is* community wiki.

Comment: winforms!!  heh ...

Comment: In more recent news, the image in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/531/957731) answer to that π question did not adapt well to the new dark mode.