# What was "the Joel Data"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, stack-overflow-history

As mentioned in the answer to [What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266208/what-is-the-first-asked-question-on-stackoverflow), the first (now deleted) question is ["Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go)

I'm sure that Joel refers to [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/AboutMe.html), but what was "the Joel Data"?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Joel Spolsky had several discussion forums on his site, one for .NET. The data from that forum is the *Joel Data*, and it was under consideration for seeding Stack Overflow in the beginning.

You can learn all about this and other SO history on the [early podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/page/57/) (link to current last page, not guaranteed to remain accurate as time passes). In [Stack Overflow podcast #11](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/podcast-11/) the data drop is mentioned; they decided not to use it to avoid a hefty .NET bias.

The forum is closed now, but the [archives are still available](http://web.archive.org/web/20160701145023/discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?pg=pgDiscussArchive&ixDiscussGroup=12).

In a comment on a [now-deleted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/what-was-the-first-question-on-so?answertab=votes#comment7627_4048), Jared Dixon stated:

> The "Joel Data" was an export of all the Joel On Software .NET discussions - we had originally imported it for our development "test" data, but decided to start fresh when we went into Stack Overflow's closed beta. In my giddiness, I asked a frivolous question - Jeff has never let me live it down :) I FEEL HIS WRATH EVEN NOW, IN THESE COMMENTS!

Comment: Is there any way we can create a link that won't need to be updated every time there's a new page worth of podcast entries?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don’t think so. Feel free to prove me wrong however!