# What was the oldest tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-overflow-history

I am curious to know what was the oldest tag on Stack Overflow. How could I find this information?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**The oldest tag is [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data)** ([which no longer exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256746)). It was used on [the very first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) ever posted to Stack Overflow, which was a nonsensical post simply used for testing the system. That question is deleted, but see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/what-was-the-first-question-on-so) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266211/366904) for details.

**The oldest tag *still in use* is [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)**, which was used on [the second question ever posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/how-to-convert-a-decimal-to-a-double-in-c). Note that was the only tag that question had as of [its initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4/1). The question itself was posted by a testing account (named ["Eggs McLaren"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301404/why-the-name-eggs-mclaren)) owned by Jeff Atwood, one of the site's founders. It is of little surprise that the first "real" tag would be C#, as the site's founders were C# programmers. The site's backend code was originally [written in C#](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165473) (you can find more details about the site's current and historical tooling and architecture [in this FAQ on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369)).

This information is relatively easy to find if you know that **all posts are numbered sequentially<sup>1</sup>**. To follow the history, you can just start enumerating posts at #1 with a bit of URL manipulation. The only major snag you'll run into is that you can't see deleted questions on the live site without having earned [>= 10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), but, luckily, the second question ever asked here is still visible publicly (and apparently a useful resource).

As [described by Charlieface, you can also query the data dump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419835) in lieu of URL manipulation.

---

<sub>**<sup>1</sup>**  Both questions *and* answers are considered "posts", so both types of posts will be included in the sequential numbering, even if you request only `/questions/`. You can distinguish between questions and answers programmatically by looking at their [`PostTypeId` field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678). And, of course, if you're browsing the site visually, I find it quite easy to tell. Post #1 is a<strike>n egg</strike> question, not a chicken. Posts #2 and #3 are answers to that first question, post #1. Post #4 is another question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks  when I have 10k reputation and become a moderator. I will find.

Comment: @Younus The good thing about 10k is that you can see all the deleted answers. The bad thing about 10k is that you can see all the deleted answers. ;)

Comment: "The site's backend code was originally written in C#"—has this changed? I can imagine that other .NET languages may have appeared, but I've always assumed that Stack Exchange's back-end was primarily written in C#.

Comment: @PM2Ring you can use [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) to hide them

Comment: They're mostly just weasel words, @Chris. As far as I know, most of SO's backend is *still* written in C#, but I don't really know too much about it these days (lots of churn, lots of new staff, lots of new projects, etc.), so I was hedging my bets and talking only about what I knew for sure, in order to avoid making an incorrect claim. As always with answers, anyone who has the time to do the research and/or the prior knowledge is always welcome to edit in more information and/or make the weasely claims more definitive. I certainly often take the liberty to do so in other answers.

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned, you can play with the URLs to get the oldest questions. But this data is also available via the SEDE data dump.

The following query gets the top 100 tags

```
SELECT TOP (100)
  s.value Tag,
  CreationDate = MIN(p.CreationDate),
  HasNonDeleted = CAST(COUNT(*) - COUNT(p.DeletionDate) AS bit)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1000)  -- limit non-grouped tags for efficiency
      p.CreationDate,
      p.DeletionDate,
      p.Tags
    FROM PostsWithDeleted p
    WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1  -- question
    ORDER BY
      p.CreationDate
) p
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(TRIM('<>' FROM p.Tags), '><', '|'), '|') s
GROUP BY
  s.value
ORDER BY
  MIN(p.CreationDate);
```

Note that the inner `TOP` is purely to limit the possible size of the resultset being grouped up, and as you move into higher numbers of rows for the outer `TOP`, that inner `TOP` needs to go up quite a lot or removed completely.

[**SEDE link**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1627176)

Results:

| Tag | CreationDate | HasNonDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | 2008-07-31 21:26:37 | FALSE |
| c# | 2008-07-31 21:42:52 | TRUE |
| decimal | 2008-07-31 21:42:52 | TRUE |
| double | 2008-07-31 21:42:52 | TRUE |
| floating-point | 2008-07-31 21:42:52 | TRUE |
| type-conversion | 2008-07-31 21:42:52 | TRUE |
| css | 2008-07-31 22:08:08 | TRUE |
| html | 2008-07-31 22:08:08 | TRUE |
| internet-explorer-7 | 2008-07-31 22:08:08 | TRUE |
| code-generation | 2008-07-31 23:33:19 | FALSE |
| j# | 2008-07-31 23:33:19 | TRUE |
| visualj# | 2008-07-31 23:33:19 | FALSE |
| .net | 2008-07-31 23:40:59 | TRUE |
| datetime | 2008-07-31 23:40:59 | TRUE |
| datediff | 2008-07-31 23:55:37 | TRUE |
| relative-time-span | 2008-07-31 23:55:37 | TRUE |
| time | 2008-07-31 23:55:37 | TRUE |
| browser | 2008-08-01 00:42:38 | TRUE |
| timezone | 2008-08-01 00:42:38 | TRUE |
| timezone-offset | 2008-08-01 00:42:38 | TRUE |
| user-agent | 2008-08-01 00:42:38 | TRUE |
| math | 2008-08-01 00:59:11 | TRUE |
| .net-3.5 | 2008-08-01 04:59:33 | TRUE |
| linq | 2008-08-01 04:59:33 | TRUE |
| web-services | 2008-08-01 04:59:33 | TRUE |
| binary-data | 2008-08-01 05:09:55 | TRUE |
| database | 2008-08-01 05:09:55 | TRUE |
| data-storage | 2008-08-01 05:09:55 | TRUE |
| mysql | 2008-08-01 05:09:55 | TRUE |
| algorithm | 2008-08-01 05:21:22 | TRUE |
| language-agnostic | 2008-08-01 05:21:22 | TRUE |
| performance | 2008-08-01 05:21:22 | TRUE |
| pi | 2008-08-01 05:21:22 | TRUE |
| unix | 2008-08-01 05:21:22 | TRUE |
| php | 2008-08-01 12:09:41 | TRUE |
| triggers | 2008-08-01 12:12:19 | TRUE |
| c++ | 2008-08-01 12:13:50 | TRUE |
| c | 2008-08-01 12:13:50 | TRUE |
| mainframe | 2008-08-01 12:13:50 | TRUE |
| sockets | 2008-08-01 12:13:50 | TRUE |
| zos | 2008-08-01 12:13:50 | TRUE |
| actionscript-3 | 2008-08-01 12:30:57 | TRUE |
| apache-flex | 2008-08-01 12:30:57 | TRUE |
| arrays | 2008-08-01 12:30:57 | TRUE |
| datatable | 2008-08-01 12:35:56 | TRUE |
| rdbms | 2008-08-01 12:35:56 | TRUE |
| sql | 2008-08-01 12:35:56 | TRUE |
| sql-server | 2008-08-01 12:35:56 | TRUE |
| timer | 2008-08-01 12:43:11 | TRUE |
| vb.net | 2008-08-01 12:43:11 | TRUE |
| alt.net | 2008-08-01 12:44:02 | FALSE |
| inversion-of-control | 2008-08-01 12:44:02 | TRUE |
| structuremap | 2008-08-01 12:44:02 | FALSE |
| architecture | 2008-08-01 12:50:18 | TRUE |
| hook | 2008-08-01 12:50:18 | TRUE |
| plugins | 2008-08-01 12:50:18 | TRUE |
| forms | 2008-08-01 13:01:17 | TRUE |
| form-submit | 2008-08-01 13:01:17 | TRUE |
| submit-button | 2008-08-01 13:01:17 | TRUE |
| file-type | 2008-08-01 13:17:20 | TRUE |
| mime | 2008-08-01 13:17:20 | TRUE |
| office-2007 | 2008-08-01 13:17:20 | TRUE |
| rdoc | 2008-08-01 13:38:27 | TRUE |
| ruby | 2008-08-01 13:38:27 | TRUE |
| aptana | 2008-08-01 13:56:33 | TRUE |
| eclipse | 2008-08-01 13:56:33 | TRUE |
| subclipse | 2008-08-01 13:56:33 | TRUE |
| svn | 2008-08-01 13:56:33 | TRUE |
| air | 2008-08-01 13:57:07 | TRUE |
| flat-file | 2008-08-01 14:19:52 | TRUE |
| linux | 2008-08-01 14:36:18 | TRUE |
| visual-c++ | 2008-08-01 14:36:18 | TRUE |
| winapi | 2008-08-01 14:36:18 | TRUE |
| branching-and-merging | 2008-08-01 14:41:24 | TRUE |
| branch | 2008-08-01 14:41:24 | TRUE |
| tortoisesvn | 2008-08-01 14:41:24 | TRUE |
| com-interop | 2008-08-01 15:12:34 | TRUE |
| memory-leaks | 2008-08-01 15:12:34 | TRUE |
| 64-bit | 2008-08-01 15:22:29 | TRUE |
| windows | 2008-08-01 15:22:29 | TRUE |
| ascii | 2008-08-01 15:23:05 | TRUE |
| hex | 2008-08-01 15:23:05 | TRUE |
| asp.net | 2008-08-01 15:50:08 | TRUE |
| sitemap | 2008-08-01 15:50:08 | TRUE |
| xml | 2008-08-01 15:50:08 | TRUE |
| csv | 2008-08-01 16:08:52 | TRUE |
| data-conversion | 2008-08-01 16:08:52 | TRUE |
| java | 2008-08-01 16:08:52 | TRUE |
| oop | 2008-08-01 16:10:30 | TRUE |
| theory | 2008-08-01 16:10:30 | TRUE |
| bcp | 2008-08-01 16:22:42 | TRUE |
| sql-server-2005 | 2008-08-01 16:22:42 | TRUE |
| xsd | 2008-08-01 16:33:38 | TRUE |
| sysadmin | 2008-08-01 16:37:51 | FALSE |
| tools | 2008-08-01 16:37:51 | FALSE |
| webmaster | 2008-08-01 16:37:51 | FALSE |
| website | 2008-08-01 16:37:51 | FALSE |
| compression | 2008-08-01 17:13:08 | TRUE |
| file | 2008-08-01 17:13:08 | TRUE |
| analytics | 2008-08-01 17:14:58 | TRUE |

Comment: Minor nitpick: the tags column holds the tags currently on the question. Later created tags can be added to older questions. PostHistory (specially rows with typeid 3 and 6) is a better source in that respect but it lacks the records for now deleted questions. This is good enough. And plus 1 for the Trim / Replace trick. That is way more elegant I ever did.

Comment: Excel messing things up as usual

Comment: Here is a full markdown table for you: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1627188/oldest-tags?opt.textResults=true based of [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360784)

Comment: Oh great, [c] and [c++] have the same timestamp, presumably both created at once on a single question tagged with both.  Off to a great start, there.  ([mainframe] [sockets] [zos] have the same timestamp, so presumably those were the other tags.)

Comment: Thanks so much that I can know all old tags without 10k reputation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is accurate. It says [decimal], [double], [floating-point] and [type-conversion] were all created at the same time as [the second question ever asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4/4284627), even though those tags were added to that question later.

Comment: rene alreadyn nitpicked on that. We have no other way of identifying tags on deleted questions.

Comment: @PeterCordes That question actually has correct tags, it's asking about interfacing between these two languages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25/how-to-use-the-c-socket-api-in-c-on-z-os