# How can I know who is the first registered member of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious about this topic

> Who is the first registered member in Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange network sites?

If I want to know such things, how can I do it?

Comment: Related: [What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266208), which also discusses test accounts and 'real' questions and accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the first user on a SE site, just type the domain name followed by `/users/1` , which will bring you the user with UserId=1 (*the first user*).

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1

redirects to

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood

Who was the first user of Stack Overflow.

Comment: While we are at it, Sneaker is more interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/users/10/sneakers-otoole

Comment: Lets not forget this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1

Comment: 'Jeff Atwood'?  What a weird way to write '[Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'