# The Stack Overflow Question URL Structure

Tags: support, hyperlinks

If you look in a Stack Overflow question URL, the structure is like this:

```
/question/<number here>
```

Out of interest, does this number actually increase by 1 with every new question, or is it a hashcode or a random number?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's each post (question and answer) that increments the id by one. For example: Take the URL of this question, remove the title at the end, and lower the number by 1. You'll get sent to an answer.

Comment: @Kendra: The title is ignored anyway, you don't even need to remove it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The identifier increases sequentially, yes, but the sequence is shared between questions and answers.

For example, your question has the id 289297, this answer's is 289298. The next post created will have id 289299, whether it is a question or an answer.

Comment: Really nice thing to know about SO. thanks.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the answer. I'll try to navigate to the (possible) the first question in SO!

Comment: @Phantom: [What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266209) :-)

Comment: Very cool! The magic of the human mind! :)

Comment: And when I "Share" a link to a question, the URL contains two identifiers, what are they ?

Comment: The last one is your own user id, the first one is the postid

Comment: @JonasCz: see [How does the announcer badge (and similar badges) know who shared the link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274713)