# What happened to the first three questions posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, stack-overflow-history

What happened to the first three questions posted on Stack Overflow?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3

I can see there are some screen grab references to the questions (and answers) in [What was the first question asked that still exists on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266208)

Is there an official story anywhere?

Comment: Not sure why the post you linked to doesn't answer your question. Test question and answers that have been deleted.

Comment: It's not the first three questions, it's the first three *posts*: one question, two answers. Most probably for testing purposes.

Comment: Amazingly, not jQuery or PHP.

Comment: Despite the URLs, they are not the first three *questions*, but the first three *posts* (the last two are *answers*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first question (and its answers) are still there, but as the question has been deleted, you need >10k reputation to see it:

[image]