# Why was the first question ever asked on Stack Overflow deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, stack-overflow-history

I am intrigued by the [first post ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) was deleted. How do I know that it's the first post ever? It's question with ID 1. When I go to [the edit page for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1/edit), it says that it's locked. Is that post spam? What's with the first post ever?

Comment: Why should it stay visible in the first place? Does it add any value to the site?

Comment: @E4netisheretodownvote OK but still, could you give me a hint what the first question ever was like?

Comment: @AwesomeElephant8232 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266208/what-was-the-first-question-asked-that-still-exists-on-stack-overflow (Although according to the Twitter account of SO, the very first question was "where are my pants?" [which was deleted at the database level](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/624575358306795522).)

Comment: @Ivar What do you mean deleted at the database level?

Comment: That a developer deleted the question directly from the database. Generally, questions on Stack Overflow are only soft-deleted, still visible to those [with >10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and the post owner themself.

Comment: @Ivar I wish I could hard-delete some of my own questions.

Answer (score 3):

The first post ever was merely a test of the system. It was not a legitimate question. The only users who had access to the site at this time were the developers building it. The test having served its purpose (the Q&A engine was confirmed to work properly), it was subsequently deleted.

As for why questions *in general* are deleted, it's because they do not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A large number of questions have been deleted for this reason over the years that the site has been operational, and many more will be deleted for this reason in the future. Deletion is just one of the ways that users and moderators work to keep the site clean. Deleting questions gets rid of the cruft that makes it hard to find good content and get high-quality answers.

See also: [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Speaking of deletion, it is worth noting that all deletions on Stack Overflow are "soft" deletions. Deleted posts are visible to users with 10k or more reputation, and they are visible to diamond moderators. Deleted posts can also be undeleted, in case the original deletion was a mistake.